# ng-repeat doesn't show rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS and started my first code sample to get github repos of a user.

My html page is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="githubViewer">

  <head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="gitHubRepoController">
    {{error}}
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>HTML Url</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
          <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.full_name}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.html_url}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

and my controller is like this

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("githubViewer",[]);

  var gitHubRepoController = function($scope, $http){
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/lakshman553/repos")
         .then(onDataDownloaded, onError);

  var onDataDownloaded = function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    $scope.repos = response.data;

  };
  $scope.error = "some value";
  var onError = function(reason) {
    $scope.error = reason;
  };
  };

  app.controller("gitHubRepoController",gitHubRepoController);
})();
```

AngularJS is loaded as it is showing the `{{error}}` is being shown on the screen as `some value`

the table header is properly loaded but nothing else is shown. Even the url is returning data when seen in broswer.

There are no errors in the console also.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you set this up on fiddle or plunkr so we can see what is happening?

Comment: did you check in console if response.data is returning data ?

Comment: when you print {{repos.length}} what do you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of your promise handlers (`onDataDownloaded`, `onErro`) to before you try to use them. [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/BQdo0SghWvxvlRjIkbJJ?p=preview)

```
(function() {
  console.log('this is the app')
  var app = angular.module("githubViewer",[]);

  var gitHubRepoController = function($scope, $http){  
    var onDataDownloaded = function(response) {
      $scope.repos = response.data;
    };
    var onError = function(reason) {
      $scope.error = reason;
    };
    $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/lakshman553/repos")
    .then(onDataDownloaded, onError);
  };

  app.controller("gitHubRepoController",gitHubRepoController);
})();
```

Comment: Another solution would be to use a function declaration instead of function statements.  function onError(reason) {... } instead of var onError = function (reason) {...};.  Hoisting causes the latter to leave onError as undefined at the point it is used in the call to $http.get.  A good explanation of hoisting can be found at http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092.

Comment: How did this work without changing the ng-controller which is mentioned in the body tag?

Comment: The HTML markup in the question is fine.  The ng-controller is set to gitHubRepoController.  The question was edited, probably after you read it initially.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your controller.

Your HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="CustomersController">
    {{error}}
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>HTML Url</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
          <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.full_name}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.html_url}}</td>
          <td>{{repo.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
```

HTML should be:

```
<body ng-controller="gitHubRepoController">
{{error}}
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>HTML Url</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="repo in repos">
        <td>{{repo.name}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.full_name}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.html_url}}</td>
        <td>{{repo.description}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("githubViewer",[]);

    var gitHubRepoController = function($scope, $http){

        var onDataDownloaded = function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            $scope.repos = response.data;
        };

        $scope.error = "some value";

        var onError = function(reason) {
            $scope.error = reason;
        };

        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/lakshman553/repos")
            .then(onDataDownloaded, onError);
    };

    app.controller("gitHubRepoController",gitHubRepoController);
})();
```

You have given the controller as `ng-controller="CustomersController"` which is wrong. If you checked the console it shows you the error clearly.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: that was a typo, corrected it in the question. thanks though